# Why can't i change the button color with css?

Tags: html, css, button

When i call the css, the button doesn't change to the right color nor to the right position. What am I doing wrong please?

```css
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  background-color: #00e70c;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static\style.css">
</head>



<body>
  <button class="btn">Click me!
    </button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try adding `./` before the `static/style.css` (and I tried also without the `./` and works super fine. try refresh or debug it with devtools

Comment: Check in your browser console if your css is loaded

Comment: go into developer tools in chrome and click on network.  Then reload the page and see if your css is loading

Answer (score 0):

You are in right way. In your code there is no issue. Result is responding as your code have to display. You added margin to (.box class) that is not added to your html but there is only CSS so that one is not reflecting to page.
So there is no error or nothing any issue in your code.
code is display the result as per your code.